# for loop in c programming

Tags: c, for-loop

```
#include<stdio.h>
int n;
struct process
{
    char name[2];
    int at;
    int bt;
    int priority;
    int st;
    int wt;
    int tat;
    int completed;
};

int main()
{
    int i;
    struct process p[n];
    
    printf("Enter no of processes:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    i=0;
    while(i<n)
    {
        printf("\nenter name of process:");
        scanf("%s",p[i].name);
        
        printf("enter arrival time:");
        scanf("%d",&p[i].at);
        
        printf("enter burst time:");
        scanf("%d",&p[i].bt);
        
        printf("enter priority:");
        scanf("%d",&p[i].priority);
        
        p[i].completed=0;
        
        i++;
    }
    
}
```

In this code  i have used a for loop for a program it has to work n times but it works for n-1 only.For example when n is 3 it is **printing 2 times only .could any one can explain reason?

Comment: You used a `while` loop, not a `for` loop. And you declared `p[n]` before assigning `n`.

Comment: Are you aware that the  `name` field can contain strings with a maximum length of 1? You probably want rather `char name[50];` or so?

Comment: @interjay Thanks for your answer and i rectified it

Comment: @Jabberwocky i just simply given  a random number don't worry about it more

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the loop.  In fact I ran it and passed 3 and it "worked" but only by some luck.  More likely you will get a Segmentation fault at some point.

Comment: @VennapusaJayaChandraReddy well, you _should_ worry. With `char name[2];` and `scanf("%s",p[i].name);` : as soon as you enter a name with more than 1 character, you get a buffer overflow which yields _undefined behaviour_ (google that term).

Comment: There is no `for` loop in this program. If you have a problem with code that has a `for` loop, post code that has a `for` loop which causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no for loop in your code.

But anyway there are two distinct problems in your code:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    struct process p[n];   // here the content of n is zero
                           // so you allocate space for zero processes
    
    printf("Enter no of processes:");
    scanf("%d",&n);        // here you ask the user to enter a value for n
                           // but it's too late, the memory for p has already
                           // been allocated based on the value of n which was 0
```

You want this:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    
    printf("Enter no of processes:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    struct process p[n];
    ...
```

The second problem is here:

```
struct process
{
    char name[2];   // name can only contain strin gs with a maximal length 
                    // of one (one char + the null char terminator
    ...
```

You probably want this (assuming your process names can be longer than 1 char):

```
    char name[50]; room for 49 character + the null terminator
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this:

```
int n;

int main() {
    struct process p[n];
    scanf("%d",&n);
}
```

When you do this, the value of `n` is uninitialized and defaults to 0.  So `struct process[n]` declares an empty array of `struct process`.

Then when you do: `scanf("%s",p[i].name)` you are just writing to arbitrary memory on your stack, and will eventually hit a segfault.

Instead do this:

```
int main() {
    int n, idx;
    struct process *p;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    p = (struct process *)malloc(sizeof(struct process) * n);

    for (idx = 0; idx < n; idx++) {
       printf("\nenter name of process:");
       scanf("%1s", p[idx].name);
       ...
    }
}
```

Using scanf is problematic too, but if you do make sure the string is no longer than the buffer that contains it plus space for the terminating `'\0'` character.

Comment: The `malloc` is not necessary, placing ` struct process p[n];` _after_  the `scanf` is enough.

Comment: True, though they should also place a limit on the allowed size of `n`, but for a small array of small structs it would be fine.

Comment: The OP tries to use a VLA, so the answer should deal with a VLA and not bring `malloc` inton the equation.

Comment: We can't really know what the OP really cares about here...